# How to display an alert when only three of nine checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, addeventlistener, selectors-api

I have implemented the following code into my website to produce an alert when three checkboxes named "correct" are checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="correct"/>

const correctInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="correct"]')];

const alertIfThree = () => {
  const checkedCorrectInputs = correctInputs.filter(input => input.checked);
  if (checkedCorrectInputs.length > 2) {
    alert('Alert');
  }
};

correctInputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', alertIfThree));
```

However, I also have 6 checkboxes named "incorrect" and when any of these checkboxes are checked I don't want the alert to be produced, even if the three "correct" checkboxes are checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="incorrect"/>
```

How can I change my code to implement this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"How can I change my code to implement this?"* Treat them as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the same logic

```
const correctInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="correct"]')];
const incorrectInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="incorrect"]')];

const alertIfThree = () => {
    const checkedCorrectInputs = correctInputs.filter(input => input.checked);
    const checkedIncorrectInputs = incorrectInputs.filter(input => input.checked);

    if (incorrectInputs.length === 0 && checkedCorrectInputs.length > 2) {
        alert('Alert');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I've just tried this and it isn't working, no alerts are being produced

Comment: what are the values you are getting for `incorrectInputs.length` and `checkedCorrectInputs.length` ?

Comment: add `console.log('incorrect lenght is: '+incorrectInputs.length+' and correct length is: '+checkedCorrectInputs.length);` after you define the checkedCorrectInputs and checkedIncorrectInputs consts, and let us know the output..

Comment: @GonrasKarols I have added the code and tried checking the three "correct" inputs first but nothing is displayed in the console. I also tried checking all of the checkboxes but there still isn't anything being displayed in the console. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check both input.checked and input.getAttribute("name") has the right value in your arrow function

Answer (score 0):

Best approach I think would be to query the incorrect checkboxes as well, and add an extra condition in your if statement..

```
 const IncorrectInputs = 
 [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="incorrect"]')]; //check the incorrect values as well..

const alertIfThree = () => {
  const checkedCorrectInputs = correctInputs.filter(input => 
  input.checked);

  const checkedIncorrectInputs = IncorrectInputs.filter(input => 
  input.checked);

  if (checkedCorrectInputs.length > 2 && checkedIncorrectInputs<=0 ) {
    alert('Alert');
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I've just tried this and it isn't working, no alerts are being produced